# Rxjs is getting AjaxObservable instead of ajax response

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5, rxjs-dom

I have the next Observable i trying to filter to get the user in network but .mapTo(phone => verifyPhoneInNetwork(phone, country)) return AjaxObservable instead of the ajax response

```
function verifyInNetwork(contacts: any, country: string) {
  const inNetworkOb = Observable
    .from(contacts)
    .map(contact => contact.phones)
    .map(phone => verifyPhoneInNetwork(phone, country))
    .first(({response}) => {
      return !response.invalid && !response.exists;
    })
    .isEmpty()
    .filter(empty => empty);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `verifyPhoneInNetowrk` returns an Observable you should use `switchMap` like so:

```
function verifyInNetwork(contacts: any, country: string) {
  const inNetworkOb = Observable
    .from(contacts)
    .map(contact => contact.phones)
    .switchMap(phone => verifyPhoneInNetwork(phone, country))
    .first(({response}) => {
      return !response.invalid && !response.exists;
    })
    .isEmpty()
    .filter(empty => empty);
```

Learn more about [switchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html).